# Change WooCommerce Checkout Button - Reverts to normal

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to change the checkout label and placeholder for the postcode field.

However using this code:

function custom_wc_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

```
$fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['placeholder'] = 'Postnummer';
$fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['label'] = 'Postnummer';
```

return $fields; 
}

Simply returns the the usual output which is "Postnummer/ZIP."

If I set it to false:
$fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['label'] = false;
Then it doesn't show up. However, if I put the placeholder to false, it still shows up.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook in your function properly, so try this before your code (in functions.php):

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_wc_checkout_fields' );
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be? 
: add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_wc_checkout_fields' );

Because I have already got this in my code, just thought it was axiomatic, so left it out.

Comment: Ah yes, good one (edited), well so long as you have that I would have thought you'd be ok. We do this with all our Woo installs. Perhaps try removing it altogether and adding it afresh as a new field.